# Как установить и показать Hint над Cluster

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Коллеги, как установить подсказку в clusters. У меня в кластере скажем 15 объектов, я это знаю. Мне надо установить Хинт, чтоб не открывать кластер и узнать что внутри, а по подсказке все увидеть. Кластеры создаются автоматически. Хелп далеко не весь понял, примеры все посмотрел, прошу помощи.

```
if (e.get('type') == 'mouseenter') { //курсор над кластером, создадим новый хинт!
var objectId = e.get('objectId');
var cluster = MySuperObjectManager.clusters.getById(objectId);
    if (cluster) {
        cluster.hintContent='123....';
        cluster.hasHint=true;
        //как показать хинт над кластером?
        //cluster.hint.open(); - не работает
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно выставить hasHint для кластеров в objectManager, тогда хинт будет при наведении мышки появляться сам.

Кроме этого, нужно устанавливать не cluster.hintContent, а cluster.properties.hintContent:

```
om = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 32,
    clusterHasHint: true
});

map.geoObjects.add(om);
om.add(getData());

om.events.add('mouseenter', e => {
    var cluster = om.clusters.getById(e.get('objectId'));
    if(!cluster){
        return;
    }
    cluster.properties.hintContent = cluster.features.map(feature => {
        return feature.properties.hintContent;
    }).join('<br/>');
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/pbneq1dw/

Comment: Keyten, спасибо!!! моя ошибка в том, что не установил - **clusterHasHint: true**, и **properties** упустил из виду!!! Огромное вам спасибо!